# Destructuring an undefined object

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

If `response` is undefined, it will fail when retrieving it's property `status` with the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

```
const {
  response,
  response: { status },
  request,
  config,
} = error as AxiosError
```

Applying a default value to `status` does not change this error. It will still choke on `response`.

e.g.

```
response: { status = 420 },
```

How can this be safely destructured? Thanks.

Comment: It's `response` that is `undefined` (not `null`), so you need to give a default value to it `const { response : {status = 420} =  {} } = error`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend avoiding using destructuring for objects that have optional properties.

If your general case is covered by

```
const {
  response,
  request,
  config
} = error as AxiosError;
```

It's easier to follow it up with a new `const` declaration using optional chaining and null coalescing:

```
const status = response?.status ?? 420;
```

Otherwise your destructuring gets awkward by having to include multiple levels of default values:

```
const {
  response,
  response: {
    status = 420
  } = {}, // this could even be { status = ### } and differ from the other default value
  request,
  config
} = error as AxiosError;
```